# How do I Insert a carriage return on a card in Trello?

Tags: trello, formatting

I have added a card to a board in Trello, and now need to edit the text on that card.

How do I insert a carriage return? I have tried the following:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>.

None of these key combinations work.

Comment: Yes, you can copy-paste one in, so they are possible.

Comment: You cannot add a return though, I want to put addresses on cards that can be copied and pasted quickly into another program when needed, without editing the address onto proper mailing lines each time...you cannot do this with Trello. If you want to work on a lyric or any kind of marketing or stuff where the line return is important, trello falls short. It needs to add this functionality to be usable for me. I have started then abandoned several projects on trello because of this shortfall.

Answer (score 14):

In Trello, card titles are single line, i.e. they can't contain a carriage return.  (It's similar to the subject line of an email)

If you'd like to include multi-line content, you can do that in the card description, or in a comment (using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>)

Answer (score 5):

While it's not possible to put in line breaks, since the columns / cards are fixed width, you can easily work around this limitation by just adding some white space until you fill in the line and the text naturally jumps to the next line.

Normal spaces will get ignored though, so go for something like ideographic space (just grab it from inside these square brackets): ]　[ or go hunting [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Comment: Please don't use the same answer for multiple questions.  If they are duplicates, please flag them as such.

Comment: The lists are _almost_ fixed-width. Actually, they do not have exactly the same width on my mobile and on my laptop (I guess that’s due to the font used or the rendering engine).

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no way to type a newline in a card’s title. However, as others said, **you can paste one in**. You may also paste in paragraph breaks, carriage returns, etc.

*Various kinds of characters related to newlines you can paste in:*
[image]

Trello will remember what you typed, and display it properly on the card’s verso:
[image]

However, Trello will display all those as either spaces or nothing on the card’s recto:
[image]

Except when editing:
[image]

So, you can record carriage returns in Trello, but you can’t see them on the cards’ rectos. Still, I did experience some inconsistencies where Trello decided to really replace newlines with ordinary spaces, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

'_____________________________ " was the only thing I could do that would work. Of course if they change card width, it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dot to force a new line like so:

```
First Line
.
.
.
Second Line
```

Hope it helps!